# Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I'm learning data structures so I'm trying to implement expression evaluation using stack in two steps (convert infix expression to postfix then use the result of it to evaluate postfix)
but I keep getting this error :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at DataStructures.StackArray.evaluatePostfix(String exp) in E:\visual studio c#\New folder\DataStructures\StackArray.cs:line 281
   at DataStructures.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\visual studio c#\New folder\DataStructures\Program.cs:line 71
```

I definitely miss something silly for some reason so I'll appreciate any advice.

```
public static string infixToPostfix(string exp)
    {
        
         var postFix = "";
      

        Stack<char> Stack = new Stack<char>();


        for(int i = 0; i < exp.Length; ++i)
        {
            char x = exp[i];

            // If the scanned character is an operand, add it to output.
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))
            {
                postFix += x;
            }
            //parentheses part
            else if (x == '(')
            {
                Stack.Push(x);
            }
            else if (x == ')')
            {
               
                while (Stack.Count>0 && Stack.Peek() != '(')
                {
                   
                    postFix += Stack.Pop();
                }
                if(Stack.Peek() == '(')
                {
                    Stack.Pop();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                
                while (Stack.Count > 0 && x <= Precedence(Stack.Peek()))
                {
                    postFix += Stack.Pop();
                }
                Stack.Push(x);
            }



        }
        //pop the remain of stack
        while(Stack.Count > 0)
        {
         postFix += Stack.Pop();
        }

        return postFix;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////




    public static int evaluatePostfix(string exp)
    {
        Stack<int> Stack = new Stack<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i < exp.Length; i++)
        {
            char x = exp[i];

            //if "x" whitespace
            if (x == ' ')
            {
                 //skip it
                continue;
            }

            
            else if (char.IsDigit(x))
            {
                //create new variable to store the extracted numbers in it 
                int num = 0;

                while (char.IsDigit(x))
                {
                    num = num * 10 + (int)(x - '0');
                    i++;
                    x = exp[i];

                }

                i--;

                Stack.Push(num);
            }


            
            else
            {
                //create two vaiables to present the two elements 
                int v1 = Stack.Pop();
                int v2 = Stack.Pop();

                // Perform arithmetic operations between 2 operands
                switch (x)
                {
                    case '+':
                        Stack.Push(v2 + v1);
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        Stack.Push(v2 - v1);
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        Stack.Push(v2 / v1);
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        Stack.Push(v2 * v1);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        return Stack.Pop();

    }
```

main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

              var infix = Console.ReadLine();
            string postFix;
            var r = StackArray.infixToPostfix(infix);
            


            Console.WriteLine($"postfix is {r}");
            //evaluate postfiix
           
            int x = StackArray.evaluatePostfix(r);
            Console.WriteLine($"result is {x}");

}
```

Comment: to avoid this exception, check `.Count >0`before `Stack.Pop()`. of course you might improve algorithm to achieve your business logic.

Comment: do you mean all conditions that have '.Count > 0' in 'infixToPostfix' method? @LeiYang

Comment: i don't mean your stack.Count>0 everywhere, i mean you should check it before `Pop`, just to avoid the exception.

Comment: which line of your code sample is producing the exception? The fact that you're getting this exception means that your algorithm is incorrect or you gave it bad input.